# Animating when a component's props updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a component that's receiving props from a parent component, in which that parent component is receiving state from my redux store. My goal here is that when that redux store updates, I want the props to flash a color indicating that it's changed. My logic so far is in the child component:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.price !== prevProps.price) {
      // Price will update correctly, but I want to make it flash a color, 
      // indicating that it's changed. I want it to also flash whenever the 
      // price DOESN'T === the previous price
    }
  }
```

I'm currently also using `styled components`, so I was wondering how I could incorporate that to make it work.

This is how I'm rendering said price:

```
render() {
  const { tradOverrides: { price } } = this.props

  return (
    <StyledDetails>
      <h3>Rent</h3>
      <p>${price}</p>
    </StyledDetails>
  )
}
```

Now, **updating the price works**, but my one and only problem is that I'm very lost on **how to apply the flash of color when it updates** (ie: price changes from $40 -> $78, $78 will flash green and then back to it's original set color.). Is there something I'm missing? Am I approaching this the wrong way by using `componentDidUpdate`? Or could this be done through `styled components`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set a flag in local state and then based on the flag, load the styled component with the CSS for flashing price. Something like this:

```
    state = {
    flashFlag:false
    }
         componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
            if (this.props.price !== prevProps.price) {
                   this.setState({flashFlag:true})
            }
            else {
             this.setState({flashFlag:false})
               }
          }


  return (
    {this.flashFlag ?
<FlashStyledDetails>
      <h3>Rent</h3>
      <p>${price}</p>
    </FlashStyledDetails> :
<StyledDetails>
      <h3>Rent</h3>
      <p>${price}</p>
    </StyledDetails>
}
  )
```

You need to add the CSS for flashing in this styled component :

```
 <FlashStyledDetails>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it comes back with an infinite loop. I'm not sure what conditions to make it trigger/not trigger

Comment: Please share your complete code , so that I can take a look .